# How to implement the MouseListener from Swing in JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx, event-handling

I have a simple login panel that I wrote using Swing and now I have to redo everything with JavaFX, but I don't know how to convert the ActionListeners/MouseListeners.

[image]

Whenever the "Neu-Anmeldung" checkbox is checked/unchecked, the values true/false should be seen in the Eclipse console.

My Swing code for this purpose:

```
// ...

this.jBoxNeuAnmeldung.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (LoginFrame.this.jBoxNeuAnmeldung.isSelected())
          neuAnmeldung = true;
        else
          neuAnmeldung = false;
        System.out
            .println("Neu-Anmeldung Checkbox angekreutzt? " + neuAnmeldung);
      }
    });

// ...
```

How do I do the same thing with JavaFX?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ...
    checkBox.setOnAction((event) -> {
        neuAnmeldung = checkBox.isSelected();
        System.out.println("Neu-Anmeldung Checkbox angekreutzt? "
                + neuAnmeldung);
    });
```

replace checkBox by check box name, e.g.

```
    final CheckBox jBoxNeuAnmeldung = new CheckBox();
    ...
    jBoxNeuAnmeldung.setOnAction((event) -> {
        neuAnmeldung = jBoxNeuAnmeldung.isSelected();
        System.out.println("Neu-Anmeldung Checkbox angekreutzt? "
                + neuAnmeldung);
    });
```

(in standard Java 8 you can also omit final in CheckBox when used in labmda expression).

Comment: Doesnt't work! Cannot make static reference to non-static method `isSelected()` from type CheckBox

Comment: checkBox is just an example, replace by the name of your variable, e.g. jBoxNeuAnmeldung.isSelected(). Note jBoxNeuAnmeldung should be either field of the object or final, otherwise you can't reference it. If you are getting this error you just copied as is and tried to correct checkBox to CheckBox (as lowercase checkbox is not a type so would give undefined error and not static reference error).

Comment: I've expanded the answer to be more specific

Comment: Glad you figured it out! In fact it is similar, you are just wiring exactly the same event in FXML instead of setting handler for this event explicitly using setOnAction )

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `ChangeListener` to the `selected` property

```
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("Neu-Anmeldung Checkbox angekreutzt? " + newValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
  public CheckBox checkBoxNeuAnmeldung;

  @FXML
  public void handleCheckBoxNeuAnmeldungAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (checkBoxNeuAnmeldung.isSelected()) {
      neuAnmeldung = true;
    } else
      neuAnmeldung = false;
    System.out.println("Neu-Anmeldung Checkbox angekreutzt? " + neuAnmeldung);
  }
```

I managed to implement a simpler method using `ActionEvent` and connected it tp my FXML file.